# Facebook API - Get all campaigns and their ids

Tags: .net, facebook, facebook-marketing-api

I am totally new to Facebook API and i have a task which will retrieve all campaigns of the current user (facebook id).

I did search a lot but only get this one 
GET /v2.10/{ad-account-id}/campaigns HTTP/1.1
Host: graph.facebook.com.

Is it a right call for me? And if it is, so how could i get ad-account-id stuff.

Thanks you all so much

Answer (score 0):

You can find the `ad_account` on `/me/adaccounts`.
There you should use the `act_<id>` one to make the call.

The call will look something like

`/act_xxxxx/campaigns?fields=name,id`